# Is there an event after the query finishes in SugarORM?

Tags: android, sqlite, events, sugarorm

I am using the sugarOrm library in android. Is there any event after query is finished or after closing the database connection.
I want to decrypt the database file before using it and encrypt it after finishing query .

Is that possible  ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an event after the query finishes in SugarORM?

I think there are no listener in the save() method. To make sure check this code from the [sugar repository](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/orm/SugarRecord.java). You will not find any listener in the save() method.

But you can do another workaround to encrypt the database file after the you save your data.